Why does codelite not show lldb-vscode in the debugger drop down menu even after installing lldb-vscode using brew?
When I am creating a new project and setting the debugger,it doesn't show lldb-vscode even though I installed lldb-viscode using brew on MacoS Sonoma 14.0 with 1.1GHz Dual core Intel Core i3.
I tried installing it using brew and re installed again from the documentation provided regarding debug adapter client but it still doesn't show in the drop down menu for selecting debugger, only gdb debugger is shown.
